# Methods of de-emphasizing some dimensions in a cluster analysis

Tags: scikit-learn, clustering

I'm trying to understand how "weightings" on different dimensions in a cluster analysis might relate to the range of values along a given dimension in the dataset.

**DATA SET**

List of 1,000 to 10,000 objects with 6 dimensions:

- X position
- Y Position
- Transparency (either 0% or 100% in this data set)
- Color (3 dimensional: RGB, HSL)

**GOAL:**
Break the objects into an unknown number of clusters.

In identifying clusters, I'd like to de-prioritize the color dimension.  It's less important than position, but it would be needed to "break ties" on the borders of position clusters.  There might be some similarly positioned objects that have different colors, and they should be placed in separate clusters

I'm using python's `scikit-learn`, although I would be open to using any other python tool. I see that there are weighting options for samples, but not for dimensions.

One approach I could use would be to limit the range of values on color.  In other words, map H, S, and L to a range between [0,0.333].  Since the other values are on a range of [0,1] then the values for widely different color values would be closer together than the position vector, so they should impact the cluster determination less.  (I would naively call this a 1/3 weighting for the color dimensions)

I'm not familiar enough with the clustering algorithms to know the implications of doing this.  With the internet search terms I've been using, I haven't been able to hit upon a good discussion of this topic of "weighting dimensions" in cluster analyses.

My questions are:  Is this method of "range shortening" an appropriate means to accomplish my goal?  Does scikit-learn or any other python library allow for an explicit dimension weight parameter in cluster analysis?  How do others accomplish this goal?  How do experts describe this sort of problem so that I can find further resources on it?